# Photo cleaning to compare with a texture catalog

Tags: image-processing

I'm implementing an application to search a photo in a catalog of textures comparing the histogram.

In order to enhance the accuracy, What processes should I apply to the photo to normalize/clean it before the matching with the catalog?

**UPDATE**

I added a actual photo made with the Android camera, and the desired match image that it's saved in the catalog.

How can I process the photo to correct colors, enhance and made posible a better match with the catalog.

[image: Photo]

[image: Catalog]

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the textures. I think the question to ask is what variation is acceptable and what variation do you want to remove from the catalog. Or put another way, which features do you care about and want to search for?

For example, if color is not important, then a step in normalizing/cleaning would be to convert all to grayscale to remove potential variations. Perhaps a more pertinent example would be that you only want to compare against the strongest edges in the texture so you would blur out the weaker edges.

It all really depends on your specific use case. Consider what you *really* want to match against and the more specific you can get, the more normalizing and cleaning you can do, and the more accurate your application will be.

Comment: I added an example image, the type of textures saved on the catalog are marble ones.

Answer (score 0):

Your question should contain example data and your solution attempt. Lets say you want to find how much does image 0.35 compression distort image.

[image]

```
img = Import["http://farm1.staticflickr.com/62/171463865_36ee36f70e.jpg"]
img2 = ImportString@ExportString[img, "JPEG", "CompressionLevel" -> 0.35]
diff = ImageSubtract[Image[img, "Real"], Image[img2, "Real"]]
ArrayPlot[0.5 + 5 ImageData[First@ColorSeparate[diff, "Red"]], 
 ColorFunction -> "RedGreenSplit", ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

The difference is slight so output difference is amplified 5 times.

[image]

Example was done using Mathematica (aka Wolfram language). Original question was about : [How can I tell exactly what changed between two images?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11735/how-can-i-tell-exactly-what-changed-between-two-images).

Other then that @Noremac is right - it really depends on your specific use case.

Comment: I would compare image and each catalog item. Compute difference image and difference value ex: sum of all pixel values in difference image. Lowest value will be catalog item, that is most similar to the image. If you get unexpected results, that you do not like, then most likely you need to adapt.

Comment: I added and example. The app is not searching the exact image, but a same kind of material.